# imagemagick force output fileformat

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert a png-image to a jpg image in imagemagick.

Usually I would use this command:

```
convert image.png image.jpg
```

This works since imagemagick determins the output format by looking at the file extension '.jpg'. Is there any commandline option for imagemagick to override this behaviour?

I would like to use something like this

```
convert image.png -outputformat jpg image.data
```

It is important for my application, that no *.jpg file is ever created in the process, so I can't "mv" it afterwards either!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found the solution:

```
convert image.png jpg:image.data
```

The `jpg:` is not written!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the -format option: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#format

Comment: @dlemstra From that link, "When used with the mogrify utility". Does that mean I can't use the `format` option with `convert` for example?

Comment: @Shawn No it doesn't. `-format` works with `convert`